# Configure the gulp bundling destination folder outside the project folder

Tags: gulp, aurelia

We have bundling our application using gulp process(using aurelia-bundler). As of now the bundle process destination folder resides inside the project folder named "dist". We need to place the destination folder outside the project folder

```
gulp.task('bundle', function (callback) {
runSequence('unbundle',
            'bundle-config',
            'copy-app-files',
            'compress',                
            function () {

            });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you just have to change the `exportSrvRoot` variable of the **build/paths.js** file. For instance:

```
//var exportSrvRoot = 'export/';
var exportSrvRoot = '../'; //this is outside of the project folder.
```

Now, the `gulp export` command will export the files to the folder above the project folder. The solution is the same for build output (gulp build/bundle), but you'd have to change the `outputRoot` variable instead of `exportSrvRoot`.

However, there is a problem in this approach. Since your export folder is outside of the project folder, if you run `gulp export`, you will get an error saying that `gulp.del` cannot delete a folder that is outside of the project folder. This could be solved by passing additional parameters to `gulp.del`, but the task uses [vinyl-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-paths) to call `gulp.del`, preventing you to send any additional parameters for it =/.

One of the ways to solve the above problem is deleting the **line 36 of the export-release.js**:

```
// use after prepare-release
gulp.task('export', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    'bundle',
    //'clean-export', <---- this line
    'export-copy',
    callback
  );
});
```

In this way, `gulp export` won't try to delete the folder, preventing the error. But now, you must delete the export folder manually before each time you run `gulp export`.

Another way to solve this is rewriting the `clean-export` task in order to remove its dependency from *vinyl-paths*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We have changed configuration but "app-bulid-" files not generating successfully in the new dist folder.

Comment: I was able to do it by modifying the bundles.json file as follows

`bundles: {
    "../../dist/app-build": {
      includes: [`

Files are generated in the specified location,
but it now throws an unable to calculate canonical name issue